# select records which are repeated twice!

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server with these records :

```
ID         Date     Time
--     ---------    ----
1      09/05/02     6:00
2      09/05/02     8:00
3      09/05/03     6:00
4      09/05/04     8:00
5      09/05/04     6:00
```

I would like to select those ID who have records in a day which are repeated twice *or multiple of two*.

How would I do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this query just select records with ID=1 and days which are repeated twice or multiple of 2 :

```
SELECT  *
FROM     MyTable
WHERE  (Date IN
          (SELECT  Date
           FROM  MyTable
           WHERE  (ID = 1)
           GROUP BY Date
          HAVING  (COUNT(Date) % 2 = 0)
          )
       )
 AND (ID = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
select table_1.id, table_1.date from
table as table_1 inner join table as table_2 on 
table_1.date = table_2.date 
and 
table_1.id <> table_2.id
```

should work alright.

Answer (score 1):

this will return the expected result

```
     declare @aa table (id int,datee date)
     insert into @aa 
    select 1, '09/05/02' union all
     select 2, '09/05/02' union all
    select 3, '09/05/03' union all
    select 4, '09/05/04' union all
    select 5, '09/05/04'    

     select * from @aa where datee in (
                select datee from @aa group by datee having COUNT(datee)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(ID INTEGER, Date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1, '09/05/02 6:00')
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1, '09/05/02 8:00')
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (2, '09/05/03 6:00')
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (3, '09/05/04 8:00')
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (4, '09/05/04 6:00')

SELECT  t1.*
FROM    MyTable t1
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  t1.ID, Date1 = t1.Date, Date2 = t2.Date
          FROM    MyTable t1
                  INNER JOIN MyTable t2 ON CAST(t2.Date AS INTEGER) = CAST(t1.Date AS INTEGER)
                                           AND DATEPART(HOUR, t2.Date) = DATEPART(HOUR, t1.Date) - 2
                                           AND t2.ID = t1.ID
        ) t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t1.Date IN (t2.Date1, t2.Date2)
```

Comment: in my real table, there are records which are repeated twice, 4 times , 6 times and ... <br/> I mean the count is even, not more than 1. can you help me?

Comment: @LIX - It is not entirely clear to me. Do you need those records where the count is exactly 2, a multiple of 2 or more than 1?

Comment: @Lieven - I need multiple of 2 and I have a problem. I need those ID which their date is 2k. like this :<br/>
1 08/05 a<br/>
1 08/05 b<br/>
2 08/05 v<br/>
3 09/05 d <br/>
and it should returns 1.

Comment: Sorry, can't make head nor tail about it. What do you mean with their date is 2k? 2000? Something else? Why does ID 1 get repeated with a & b? Where is the a, b, v & d suddenly coming from? It should return 1? I'd suggest you edit your question, give a complete as possible sample of input and what **exactly** you expect as output.

Comment: time and date are separate fields! this is a card system and each record means the time that employees enter or exit. I need records that they use their cards to enter AND exit, not persons who just use their card once in that day. your first query didn't work in this situation. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me from your layout whether the date and the time are in separate columns, or just one.  That is, do you have

```
ID    theDate    theTime
--    --------   -------
1     09/05/02   6:00
1     09/05/02   8:00
2     09/05/03   6:00
3     09/05/04   8:00
4     09/05/04   6:00
```

or

```
ID    theDateTime
--    -------------
1     09/05/02 6:00
1     09/05/02 8:00
2     09/05/03 6:00
3     09/05/04 8:00
4     09/05/04 6:00
```

If the first is true, as it seems, then Ramesh has nearly, but not quite, the correct answer:

```
select *
from theTable
where theDate in (
    select theDate 
    from theTable
    group by theDate
    having count(theDate) % 2 = 0
)
```

If the second is true, your job is significantly more complex - I'll take a think about it.